# Insert a getElementById inside a progress bar value=""

Tags: javascript, php, html

How can i add the result of this simple script in a value="" of a progress bar?

```
<script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (100 + 50) * 3;
</script>
```

Like this

```
<progress ... value="document.getElementById('demo')">
```

Thanks

[image]

Comment: You mean other than `<progress value="450">`? You can’t really do that without JS.

Comment: Give your `<progress...>` an id and update then call `document.getElementById(progressID).value = (100+50) * 3;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use JavaScript to set its `value` property:

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
<progress max="10">
<script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.querySelector('progress').value = 7;
</script>
```

With a `meter` tag:

```html
<meter min="28900" max="31100" value="30000">
```

Comment: @paulmagmusik Consider using [`<meter>`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meter) instead.

Comment: Can you post me an example maybe? Thanks!

Comment: @paulmagmusik I've added an example in my post.

Comment: Is it possible that you help me again? I guess it is a small task for you. I want the same function and progress but change value to style and add before and behind this. width: RESULT%